Rotation of area
I'm trying to illustrate the rotation of the area 0≤y≤1-x^2, 0≤x≤1, when y=1-x^2 is rotated around y=1, and calculate the volume. I read Volume of a region of revolution but could not find a way to apply it. Help is much appreciated.

Method-1

We integrate the circles whose center is on the line y=1 and radius is the distant from the point to the line y=1.

reg = ImplicitRegion[{0 <= y <= 1 - x^2, 0 <= x <= 1}, {x, y}];
line = InfiniteLine[{0, 1}, {1, 0}];
RegionPlot[reg, 
 Epilog -> {Red, line, Point[{.6, .4}], Blue, 
   Arrow[{{.6, .4}, {.6, 1}}]}]
Integrate[2 π*RegionDistance[line, {x, y}], {x, y} ∈ reg]


(4 π)/5.


Method-2

We integrate the area of Annulus[{0, 0}, {x^2, 1}] from 0 to 1.

reg = ImplicitRegion[{0 <= y <= 1 - x^2, 0 <= x <= 1}, {x, y}];
RegionPlot[reg, 
 Epilog -> {Red, line, Blue, Arrow[{{.6, 0}, {.6, 1 - .6^2}}]}]
Integrate[π (1^2 - (x^2)^2), {x, 0, 1}]



(4 π)/5.

Method-3
Clear[reg];
reg=ImplicitRegion[{0 <= x <= 1, 
  0 <= 1 - EuclideanDistance[{x, y, z}, {x, 1, 0}] <= 1 - x^2}, {x, y, z}];
reg//Region
reg//Volume

Method-4
reg1 = ParametricRegion[{{x, 1, 
     0} + {0, (1 - y) Cos[t], (1 - y) Sin[t]}, {0 <= x <= 1, 
    0 <= y <= 1 - x^2, 0 <= t <= 2 π}}, {x, y, z, t}]
reg1//Region
volume=reg1 // Volume


or
ParametricRegion[{{x, y, z}, {0 <= x <= 1, 
    0 <= y0 <= 1 - x^2, (y - 1)^2 + z^2 == (1 - y0)^2}}, {x, y, z, 
   y0}] // Volume

but such result contain a small imaginary part, maybe a bug( 11.3,12.2 get the correct result (4 π)/5 ).


To get a smooth surfaces, we use rotation transforamtion RotationTransform[t, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}]

{ParametricPlot3D[{RotationTransform[
       t, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}] /@ {{x, 1 - x^2, 0}, {x, 0, 0}}} // 
    Evaluate, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2    π}, Mesh -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5], Boxed -> False, 
   AxesLabel -> {Style["x", 20, Blue, Bold], 
     Style["y", 20, Blue, Bold]}], 
  ParametricPlot3D[
   RotationTransform[t, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}]@{0, y, 0} // 
    Evaluate, {y, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2    π}, Boxed -> False, 
   Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5]], 
  Region[ImplicitRegion[{0 <= y <= 1 - x^2, 0 <= x <= 1, z == 0}, {x, 
     y, z}], BaseStyle -> Red], 
  Graphics3D[{Blue, Arrow@Tube@{{0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}}]} // Show


Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"];
poly2d = 
  Polygon@MeshPrimitives[
      BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@
       ImplicitRegion[{0 <= y <= 1 - x^2, 0 <= x <= 1}, {x, y}], 
      1][[;; , 1]][[;; , 1]];
poly3d = RegionProduct[poly2d, Point[{0}]];
shape = OpenCascadeShape[poly3d];
sweep = OpenCascadeShapeRotationalSweep[
   shape, {{0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0} + {1, 0, 0}}, 2 π];
bmesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[sweep, 
   "ShapeSurfaceMeshOptions" -> {"AngularDeflection" -> 0.1}];
reg = BoundaryMeshRegion[bmesh];
bmesh["Wireframe"[
  "MeshElementStyle" -> Directive[FaceForm[Cyan], EdgeForm[]], 
  Lighting -> "ThreePoint"]]


Is it possible to get a 3D-image of the revolution body also? And, how can the command Volume be used? I found this command interesting.

@cvgmt Excellent instructive answer. Thank you. +1 :)

@cvgmt thanks for spotting error. Missed exponent in x2. ¯_(ツ)_/¯.  I hope I have corrected now.

@cvgmt in Method - 1. How can I find the point {.6, .4}?

@ThuyNguyen  {.6,.4} is any point in the plane area.

I got incorrect result with
poly2d =    Polygon@MeshPrimitives[       BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@        ImplicitRegion[{0 <= y <= Sin[x], 0 <= x <= 2  Pi}, {x, y}],        1][[;; , 1]][[;; , 1]];

@minhthien_2016  The result is right since the rotation axis is from {0,1,0} to {0,1,0}+{1,0,0} instead of x axis. If we wan to rotate around x axis, we need to set sweep = OpenCascadeShapeRotationalSweep[    shape, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0} + {1, 0, 0}}, 2  π]; .

I have voted for @cvgmt excellent answer.
Just to add a method.
(*volume of enclosing cylinder-volume of complement of region of interest relative to enclosing cylinder*) 
Pi - Integrate[r , {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {z, 0, 1}, {r, 0, z^2}]

yields $4\pi/5$
Just another way to show enclosing surfaces:
ParametricPlot3D[{{u, Cos[v], 
   1 + Sin[v]}, {u , u^2 Cos[v], u^2 Sin[v]} + {0, 0, 1}}, {u, 0, 
  1}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> False, Boxed -> False, 
 Background -> Black, Axes -> False]



I probably made an error. I’ll delete and correct

@cvgmt thanks for spotting error. Missed exponent in x2. ¯_(ツ)_/¯. I hope I have corrected now
